# How to require some properties based on another property in JSONSchemaType?

Tags: typescript, ajv

```
interface CreateBookingBody {
    enquiryUuid: string;
    countryProductId: number;
    sourceId: number;
    gateway?: PaymentGateways['id'];
    successCallbackUrl?: string;
    failureCallbackUrl?: string;
    /** Bank name if gateway is Bank Transfer */
    bankName?: string;
    /** Transaction reference number */
    txnReferenceNumber?: Orders['pgTxnId'];
    /** Transaction date */
    txnDate?: string;
    /** Receipt doc url */
    receiptUrl?: string;
    /** Cheque number */
    chequeNumber?: string;
    /** Cheque date string DD/MM/YYYY */
    chequeDate?: string;
    /** Cheque doc url */
    chequeUrl?: string;
    /** return pg form */
    pgForm?: boolean;
}


const bodySchema: JSONSchemaType<CreateBookingBody> = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
    enquiryUuid: { type: 'string', format: 'uuid' },
    countryProductId: { type: 'number' },
    sourceId: { type: 'number' },
    gateway: { type: 'number', nullable: true },
    successCallbackUrl: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
    failureCallbackUrl: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
    bankName: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
    txnReferenceNumber: { type: 'string', nullable: true }, // Orders.pgTxnId
    txnDate: { type: 'string', format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', nullable: true },
    receiptUrl: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
    chequeNumber: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
    chequeDate: { type: 'string', format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', nullable: true },
    chequeUrl: { type: 'string', nullable: true },
    pgForm: { type: 'boolean', nullable: true },
    },
    required: ['enquiryUuid', 'countryProductId', 'sourceId'],
    additionalProperties: false,
};
```

for certain `gateway` value i want to require some additional properties in schema. Let's say for `gateway = 1`  i want `['bankName', 'txnReferenceNumber', 'txnDate', 'receiptUrl']`. For `gateway = 2`  i want `['chequeNumber', 'chequeDate', 'chequeUrl']`. `gateway` can have other values and it can be also null.

i tried adding

```
oneOf: [
                {
                    // Bank Transfer
                    properties: { gateway: { const: OFFLINE_PAYMENT_MODE.BANK_TRANSFER.id } },
                    required: ['bankName', 'txnReferenceNumber', 'txnDate', 'receiptUrl'],
                },
                {
                    // Cheque
                    properties: { gateway: { const: OFFLINE_PAYMENT_MODE.CHEQUE.id } },
                    required: ['chequeNumber', 'chequeDate', 'chequeUrl'],
                },
            ],
```

doesn't work. oneOf requires the property even when i am not providing gateway in body object.
I also tried `if then` with `anyOf`, couldn't find a solution.
Then i tried creating `required` array dynamically like this

```
function getRequired() {
            const required: (keyof CreateBookingBody)[] = [];

            if (req.body.gateway === OFFLINE_PAYMENT_MODE.BANK_TRANSFER.id) {
                required.push('bankName', 'txnReferenceNumber', 'txnDate', 'receiptUrl');
            }
            else if (req.body.gateway === OFFLINE_PAYMENT_MODE.CHEQUE.id) {
                required.push('chequeNumber', 'chequeDate', 'chequeUrl');
            }

            return Object.freeze(required);
        }
```

and then using this function like this `['enquiryUuid', 'countryProductId', 'sourceId', ...getRequired()]`

But then typescript throws error that `Types of property 'required' are incompatible. Type '(keyof CreateBookingBody)[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly UncheckedRequiredMembers<CreateBookingBody>[]'` and since ajv doesn't export `UncheckedRequiredMembers` i can't explicitly cast required array.